# did Anakin bring "balance to the force" by killing all jedi?

Tags: star-wars

In the later trilogy, it is stated various times that Anakin could be the choosen one that "bring balance to the force"
At the end of the episode 3, there is only left 2 jedi and 2 siths...

Could it be that the prophecy was misinterpreted and that Anakin did bring the balance by killing nearly all jedi?

Answer (score 1):

George is a pretty bad writer, and unfortunately by the time of the prequels everyone who worked with him was scared of him. So no one told him anything about the scripts didn't make sense, let alone take it out of his hand and force rewrites using professional script writers. He has however stated that the idea of bringing balance to the force was destroying the Sith. Basically he meant balance as a vague term for "good outcome." Obviously there are some holes that can be poked in this, in that it has nothing to do with "balance," and it seems pretty unlikely that evil Force users were put to an end just because Darth Vader threw Palpatine down a shaft.

Comment: This seems like more of a rant than anything. Maybe it could be turned into a good answer if you provide a source for your statement "He has however stated that..."

Comment: "it seems pretty unlikely that evil Force users were put to an end just because Darth Vader threw Palpatine down a shaft" - Actually...infighting, backstabbing, and betrayals of the lethal variety are a hallmark of Sith culture.  In that sense Vader throwing Palpatine down a shaft may be a fairly apt metaphor about what happened to any other Sith that might exist.  Somewhat off base since Vader was actually acting for altruistic reasons.  But there's no reason to think that Palpatine wasn't exterminating Sith just as relentlessly as Jedi to secure his own position of superiority/power.